# Symfony 2 livecycle - don't update | PHPCR

Tags: php, symfony, livecycle, post-update

I have problem with my phpcr document.

I try to implement, upload file like http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html but I have problem with file changing.

It look like sf2 doesn't see any changes.
When I changed (for example) name field and photo it's ok, but if I changed photo only I haven't any changes.

My code :
Document ( entity )

```
    /**
     * @PHPCR\String
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file = null;

 /**
     * @PHPCR\PrePersist()
     * @PHPCR\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {        
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {            
            $this->setImage(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.jpg');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @PHPCR\PostPersist()
     * @PHPCR\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getImage()
        );

        $this->file = null;
    }
```

Summarizing: If I change file only LiveCycle ( preUpdate and postUpdate ) doesn't work.

Comment: This part of the code does not shown, but you must ensure in `setFile` method any changes in one of the mapped properties for LiveCycle it work. The `file` field is not mapped. Consider using this bundle https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle.